# Select Statement in SQLite Python - Using Variables in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Say I have a class variable *restemail* which stores the email id I need to use to sort out from the select statement in SQLite (Python). Whenever I refer to that variable after my WHERE clause, SQLite treats it as a column and returns an error saying that such a column doesn't exist. Something like this:

```
  restemail=StringVar()
  Password=StringVar()

  def database(self):
      conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
      with conn:
            cursor=conn.cursor()
      strrest = self.restemail
      cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Restaurant3 WHERE restemail = strrest')
```

Can someone tell me how to use a variable inside my SQL queries without it being treated as a column name?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the sqlite3 variable substitution syntax:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Restaurant3 WHERE restemail = ?', (strrest,))
```

Comment: This gives me this error:
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the SQL type of `restemail`, and what is the Python type of `strrest`?  There's a mismatch there.  Maybe try `str(strrest)`

To get the SQL type of `restemail` do `.schema Restaurant3` at the interactive sqlite3 prompt.

Comment: Ah Yes I just did strrest = self.restemail.get() (changing it to string). Type for restemail was TEXT. Thanks it is working now!